# Pythonic way to make products from word lists

Tags: python

I am learning Python trough Coursera (Dr. Chuck!) and just finished my first 'useful' personal script outside the homework assignments.

It basically uses two lists of words/digits and creates all possible combinations from those items. I will use this to brute force an old password protected file of which I am sure of the elements (but not the combination).

The script is finally functioning, after hours of fiddling.
My question is if this is a 'Pythonic' way to write code. It might be important to learn it the right way from the beginning.

```
import itertools

beginfile = open('/Users/Mat/Python/combinations/begin.txt')
beginlist = []
for line in beginfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    beginlist.append(line)
    if line.islower():
        capital = line.title()
        beginlist.append(capital)

endfile = open('/Users/Mat/Python/combinations/end.txt')
endlist = []
for line in endfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    endlist.append(line)

x = itertools.product(beginlist, endlist)
counter = 0
for i in x:
    print("".join(i))
    counter += 1

print ('TOTAL:', counter, 'items')
```

Comment: Working code that only needs review is off-topic for StackOverflow, but you've got a good question with code that is better suited for [SE's Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Aren't you asked not to disclose your solutions in that course?

Comment: I did not know that, downshift. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools

with open('/Users/Mat/Python/combinations/begin.txt') as beginfile:
    beginlist = [line.rstrip().title() for line in beginfile if line.rstrip().islower()]

with open('/Users/Mat/Python/combinations/end.txt') as endfile:
    endlist = [line.rstrip() for line in endfile]

x = itertools.product(beginlist, endlist)
data = ["".join(i) for i in x]

print ('TOTAL:', len(data), 'items')
```

Comment: can you try this out, this is the most pythonic way I can think of :P

Comment: close the files, or better yet use the `with` context manager

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's slightliy different but I definitely see where you are going and it looks way more concise!
Differences are that my original script put both the lowercase and Title Case versions of words in the list, which I needed for the possible passwords. In addition, it also printed the list (and not only the length).
But still, great work! Real neat solution :)

Comment: @pramod mind if I edit this to open the files with the `with` context managers? That ensures they will be closed regardless of what else happens in the script